error while running my php laravel program

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `site_settings` order by `created_at` desc limit 1)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("could not find driver")


run my laravel application

What's in the DB_CONNECTION= value in your .env file? What's in the corresponding value in config/database.php under the 'connections' key?

Did you set in config/database.php the default connection? You can also check in .env file if there's DB_CONNECTION=mysql for example. The "mysql" string should be the same name of the connection that exists in config/database.php

You need to uncomment the "pdo_mysql" extension from your php.ini file,
just remove the ";" form the start of the following line:
;extension=pdo_mysql.so

